# Probability of $k \in \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ people sharing the same birthday in a room of $n$ people

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In a room of $n$ people, what is the probability that at least $k \in \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ people all share a common birthday?

For example, what is the probability that at least 5 people all share the same birthday in a room of a 1000 people.

I have found a [formula on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) for solving this problem when $k = 2$ but I would like to be able to solve for $n > 365$ and $k > 2$.

I know that $p(k \text{ people share the same birthday}) = 1$ for $k = \lceil\frac{n}{365}\rceil$ but I don't know how to solve beyond this point. I assume there are $365^n$ different ways the birthdays of $n$ people can be distributed within a year hence I am struggling to reach an answer using a combinatorial approach.

I have researched this problem online but most answers stop at the probability of one or more shared birthday in a group of 60 people max.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the reason no one wants to do this calculation is that it's messy. This is $1$ minus the probability that every birthday is shared by at most $k-1$ people. To compute this, let $f_{n, k}$ be the number of ways $n$ people can have birthdays such that every birthday is shared by at most $k-1$ people, so that we want to compute $1 - \frac{f_{n, k}}{365^n}$. General results imply that $f$ has an exponential generating function

$$\boxed{ \sum_n f_{n, k} \frac{t^n}{n!} = \left( \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{t^i}{i!} \right)^{365} }.$$

For example, to find the probability for $k = 5, n = 1000$ as you ask for we need the coefficient of $t^{1000}$ in $\left( 1 + t + \frac{t^2}{2} + \frac{t^3}{6} + \frac{t^4}{24} \right)^{365}$. As far as I know, this is about as good as it gets for the exact count. You should be able to expand this out in a good computer algebra system but it's a little too big for WolframAlpha.

So instead of asking for the exact count let's ask for an approximation. There is a Poisson approximation available here, generalizing the one discussed on Wikipedia: the number of people having a given birthday is approximately Poisson with mean $\frac{n}{365}$, and moreover for different birthdays these Poisson random variables are approximately independent. This means that the probability that every birthday is shared by at most $k-1$ people is approximately

$$\frac{f_{n,k}}{365^n} \approx \left( \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{ \left( \frac{n}{365} \right)^i}{i!} e^{- \frac{n}{365}} \right)^{365} = \boxed{ e^{-n} \left( \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{ n^i}{365^i i!} \right)^{365} }.$$

This is actually much better; in particular for $k = 5, n = 1000$ this is now a computation we can easily ask WolframAlpha to do. It gives

$$\frac{f_{1000, 5}}{365^{1000}} \approx e^{-1000} \left( 1 + \frac{1000}{365} + \frac{1000^2}{365^2 2!} + \frac{1000^3}{365^3 3!} + \frac{1000^4}{365^4 4!} \right)^{365} \approx \boxed{ 3 \times 10^{-25} }$$

so the probability that in a group of $1000$ people at least $5$ share the same birthday is very close to $1$.

To get a better sense of how these numbers behave we could ask: for a given $n$, such as $n = 1000$, about what value of $k$ do we need for this probability to no longer be very small like this? In other words, what can we say about the distribution of the *largest* cluster of people sharing the same birthday? In the Poisson approximation this is equivalent to asking: what is the distribution of the maximum of $365$ iid Poisson random variables with mean $\frac{n}{365}$? It's [known](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.4373) that this distribution clusters closely around

$$\frac{\log 365}{W \left( \frac{\log 365}{e \frac{n}{365} } \right)}$$

where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), which is complicated-looking but for large $n$ grows roughly like $\frac{en}{365}$ and in any case for $n = 1000$ evaluates to about $\boxed{12}$. This could be tested experimentally by generating some random birthday distributions, as well as by substituting $k = 10, 11, 12, 13, 14$ into the Poisson approximation above.

**Edit:** An alternative argument which produces a rigorous upper bound starting from the generating function is the following. Write $p(t) = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{t^i}{i!}$. Applying the [saddle point bound](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2016/05/20/the-man-who-knew-partition-asymptotics/) to the generating function gives

$$\frac{f_{n, k}}{n!} \le \frac{p(r)^{365}}{r^n}$$

for any $r > 0$. The optimal value of $r$ is obtained by setting the logarithmic derivative of the RHS to zero; this gives $365 \frac{p'(r)}{p(r)} - \frac{n}{r} = 0$, which is complicated, but if we're willing to approximate $\frac{p'(r)}{p(r)} \approx 1$ then this gives $r \approx \frac{n}{365}$ which is much easier to work with. We get a bound

$$\frac{f_{n, k}}{n!} \le \frac{\left( \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{ \left( \frac{n}{365} \right)^i}{i!} \right)^{365}}{ \left( \frac{n}{365} \right)^n }$$

and rearranging this, then using the crude Stirling inequality $n! \le en \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n$, we get a rigorous upper bound

$$\boxed{ \frac{f_{n, k}}{365^n} \le \frac{n}{e^{n-1}} \left( \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{n^i}{365^i i!} \right)^{365} }$$

which is very similar to the above bound, and we could improve it a bit by using a more accurate form of Stirling's approximation and
a bit more by estimating $r$ more accurately, and a bit more by using a more precise version of the saddle point bound. In any case this bound gives, similar to the above,

$$\frac{f_{1000, 5}}{365^{1000}} \le \frac{1000}{e^{999}} \left( 1 + \frac{1000}{365} + \frac{1000^2}{365^2 2!} + \frac{1000^3}{365^3 3!} + \frac{1000^4}{365^4 4!} \right)^{365} \approx \boxed{ 9 \times 10^{-22} }.$$

Answer (score -1):

if $n>365$ then by pigeonhole principle at least 2 share the same birthday.

pigeonholes = 365, pigeons = $n$.

in fact if $n=365k+1$ then at least $k+1$ people share the same birthday.

for $n\leq 365$ use the probability that no one was born on the same day.

so we have:

$q=1/365*1/364*...*1/(365-n+1)$

then $p=1-q$ is the probability for at least 2 people sharing same birthday.

Comment: This is not an answer to the OP's question.